# Comparing qsort with std::sort

Tags: c++, dictionary, std, stdmap, qsort

[I am referring you to a previous link that compares the performance of qsort vs stdsort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708105/performance-of-qsort-vs-stdsort).

I have written a C program that populates a large `std::map` and I want to sort the array.I am currently using `qsort`.

```
typedef std::map<uint16_t, uint32_t> TSrcMap;
TPSrcMap sp;
TSrcMap::iterator its;
/*Code to populate the array_start.*/

/*Code to populate the array_end.*/

typedef struct port_count
{
        uint32_t port_number;
        uint32_t port_count;
}port_count_t;

port_count_t pcount[10];
memset(pcount,0,sizeof(pcount));
size_t structs_len = sizeof(pcount)/sizeof(port_count_t);
for(its = stcp.begin(); its != stcp.end();its++)
{
      if(pcount[smallest_index].port_count < (*its).second)
      {
            pcount[smallest_index].port_count = (*its).second;
            pcount[smallest_index].port_number = (*its).first;
            /*qsort(pcount, structs_len, sizeof(port_count_t), struct_cmp_by_port_count);*/
            std::sort(pcount,sizeof(port_count_t));
      }
}
```

The `qsort` function is correctly sorting the array. I want to compare the performance of `qsort` with `std::sort` but the call `std::sort` call is giving a compile error

> no matching function for call to `‘sort(port_count_t [10], long
>   unsigned int)’`

I would like to compare the performance of `std::sort` with `qsort` algorithm. How do I do that?

Comment: If you consider your question answered, please accept the corresponding answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The signature of `std::sort()` is:

```
template <class RandomAccessIterator, class StrictWeakOrdering>
void sort(RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last,
          StrictWeakOrdering comp);
```

So it requires two *iterators* and a *comparator*, not a pointer and a length. To fix your code, call

```
std::sort(pcount, pcount+structs_len, cmp_port_count);
```

assuming that `cmp_port_count` is your comparator function which takes two `port_count_t` objects by reference and returns `true` when the first argument is to be ordered before the second argument, `false` otherwise.

Comment: +1. The last part is important; `std::sort` uses a different convention for the comparator.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling:

```
std::sort(pcount,pcount + 10);
```

std::sort takes as arguments a begin and an end iterator. So in order to sort an array you pass a pointer to the beginning of the array and a pointer to one element after the end of the array(which is always array_pointer + array_size).