# order a dataframe by column in Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp

Is there any easy way to order a DataFrame by two (or more or one) of its columns within RCpp?

There are many sorting algorithms available on the net, or I can use `std::sort` with a wrapper for DataFrame, but I was wondering if there is something already available within either RCpp or RCppArmadillo?

I need to do this sorting / ordering as a part of another function

```
DataFrame myFunc(DataFrame myDF, NumericVector x) {
  //// some code here
  DataFrame myDFsorted = sort (myDF, someColName1, someColName2) // how to sort??
  //// some code here
}
```

I would like to avoid accessing R's `order` function within RCpp (for retaining speed of the RCpp code).

Many thanks

Answer (score 12):

The difficulty is that a data frame is a set of vectors, potentially of different types; We need a way to order them independently of these types (integer, character, ...). In dplyr, we have developed what we call vector visitors. For this particular problem, what we need is a set of `OrderVisitor`, which exhibit the following interface:

```
class OrderVisitor {
public:
    virtual ~OrderVisitor(){}

    /** are the elements at indices i and j equal */
    virtual bool equal(int i, int j) const  = 0 ;

    /** is the i element less than the j element */
    virtual bool before( int i, int j) const = 0 ;

    virtual SEXP get() = 0 ;

} ;
```

dplyr then has implementations of `OrderVisitor` for all types we are supporting in this [file](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/master/inst/include/dplyr/OrderVisitorImpl.h) and we have a dispatcher function `order_visitor` that makes an `OrderVisitor*` from a vector.

With this, we can store a set of vector visitors into a `std::vector<OrderVisitor*>`; The [OrderVisitors](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/master/inst/include/dplyr/Order.h#L8) has a constructor taking a `DataFrame` and a `CharacterVector` of names of vectors we want to use for the ordering.

```
OrderVisitors o(data, names ) ;
```

Then we can use the [`OrderVisitors.apply` method](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/master/inst/include/dplyr/Order.h#L76) which essentially does lexicographic ordering:

```
IntegerVector index = o.apply() ;
```

The `apply` method is implemented by simply initializing an `IntegerVector` with `0..n` and then `std::sort` it according to the visitors.

```
inline Rcpp::IntegerVector OrderVisitors::apply() const {
    IntegerVector x = seq(0, nrows -1 ) ;
    std::sort( x.begin(), x.end(), OrderVisitors_Compare(*this) ) ;
    return x ;
}
```

The relevant thing here is how the `OrderVisitors_Compare` class implements `operator()(int,int)` :

```
inline bool operator()(int i, int j) const {
    if( i == j ) return false ;
    for( int k=0; k<n; k++)
        if( ! obj.visitors[k]->equal(i,j) )
            return obj.visitors[k]->before(i, j ) ; 
    return i < j ;
}
```

So at this point `index` gives us the integer indices of the sorted data, we just have to make a new `DataFrame` from `data` by subsetting `data` with these indices. For this we have another kind of visitors, encapsulated in the `DataFrameVisitors` class. We first create a [`DataFrameVisitors`](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/master/inst/include/dplyr/DataFrameVisitors.h) :

```
DataFrameVisitors visitors( data ) ;
```

This encapsulates a `std::vector<VectorVisitor*>`. Each of these `VectorVisitor*` knows how to subset itself with an integer vector index. This is used from `DataFrameVisitors.subset`:

```
template <typename Container>
DataFrame subset( const Container& index, const CharacterVector& classes ) const {
    List out(nvisitors);
    for( int k=0; k<nvisitors; k++){
       out[k] = get(k)->subset(index) ;    
    }
    structure( out, Rf_length(out[0]) , classes) ;
    return (SEXP)out ;
}
```

To wrap this up, here is a simple function using tools developped in dplyr:

```
#include <dplyr.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(dplyr)]]

using namespace Rcpp ;
using namespace dplyr ;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
DataFrame myFunc(DataFrame data, CharacterVector names) {
  OrderVisitors o(data, names ) ;
  IntegerVector index = o.apply() ;

  DataFrameVisitors visitors( data ) ;
  DataFrame res = visitors.subset(index, "data.frame" ) ;
  return res ;  
}
```

Comment: Can you explain `myFunc` line by line.

Comment: @RomainFrancois, the code compiles fine by using `sourceCpp`, but RStudio crashes every time I call `myFunc`. Not sure why.

Comment: @uday I think this was fixed by [this commit](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/commit/34fd72948fb262660dbbf1e0e42ecd53b8cb19ae). Gabor, I will expand on this answer.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck I hope his gives you enough details.

Comment: @RomainFrancois, has that new version of `dplyr` released?

Comment: @uday you can get the development version from github. `install_github( "hadley/dplyr" )`

Comment: It seems like this does not work anymore (cf https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50828119/ordering-dataframe-using-rcpp-dplyr#comment88665537_50828119). Can you provide an update?

Answer (score 3):

Because a `data.frame` is really a list of columns at the C++, you would have to re-order all your columns individually given a new ording index.  This is different from how `[.., ..]` indexing works in R for a `data.frame`.

See e.g. [this Rcpp Gallery article on sorting vectors](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/sorting/) for some pointers.
You will probably have to supply the new ordering index to be used, after which it is just an indexing question -- and that too has some posts on the Gallery.

[This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10287924/c-fastest-way-to-sort-a-list-of-number-and-their-index) may get you started on the index creation; [this bytes.com post](http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/577056-how-return-index-sorted-vector) discusses the same idea.

*Edit:* And [Armadillo has function](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#sort_index) `sort_index()` and `stable_sort_index()` to create the index you need for re-arranging your columns.  This only covers the one column case, and is limited to numerical columns, but is a start.