# Ordering dataframe using Rcpp & Dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, rcpp

first post on this forum so feel free to go easy :-)

I am trying to sort a dataframe using Rcpp/dplyr. Based on an earlier
post from Romain - the idea is to use the OrderVisitor class as explained in this post.

[order a dataframe by column in Rcpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23966158/order-a-dataframe-by-column-in-rcpp)

My problem is I cannot compile the MyFunc code below as defined in above post.

C++:

```
enter code here

#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <dplyr.h>

using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace dplyr;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
// [[Rcpp::depends(dplyr)]]


DataFrame myFunc(DataFrame data, CharacterVector names) {
    OrderVisitors o(data, names ) ;
    IntegerVector index = o.apply() ;

    DataFrameVisitors visitors( data ) ;
    DataFrame res = visitors.subset(index, "data.frame" ) ;

    return res;  
}
```

RStudio Compile message:

> sessioninfo::session_info()
>   ─ Session info ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
>    setting  value
>    version  R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
>    os       Windows 7 x64 SP 1
>    system   x86_64, mingw32
>    ui       RStudio
>    language (EN)
>    collate  English_United States.1252
>    tz       Australia/Sydney
>    date     2018-06-13

─ Packages ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 package     * version date       source
 clisymbols    1.2.0   2017-05-21 CRAN (R 3.4.4)
 sessioninfo   1.0.0   2017-06-21 CRAN (R 3.4.4)
 withr         2.1.2   2018-03-15 CRAN (R 3.4.4)
 yaml          2.1.14  2016-11-12 CRAN (R 3.4.1)

> Rcpp::sourceCpp('C:/temp/test.cpp')
>   c:/RBuildTools/3.4/mingw_64/bin/g++  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG   -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/library/Rcpp/include" -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/library/dplyr/include" -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/library/BH/include" -I"C:/temp"   -I"d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c test.cpp -o test.o
>   In file included from C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/library/dplyr/include/dplyr.h:4:0,
>                    from test.cpp:2:
>   C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/library/dplyr/include/dplyr/main.h:11:19: fatal error: plogr.h: No such file or directory
>    #include 
>                      ^
>   compilation terminated.
>   make: *** [test.o] Error 1
>   Warning message:
>   running command 'make -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/etc/x64/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXXLD)' SHLIB="sourceCpp_2.dll" WIN=64 TCLBIN=64 OBJECTS="test.o"' had status 2 
>   Error in Rcpp::sourceCpp("C:/temp/test.cpp") : 
>     Error 1 occurred building shared library.

so what I want to know is :

1. Any idea how to compile above code properly? Any issues with plogr?
2. Any other efficient way of achieving the same result using Rcpp?

Thanks.

MSW

Comment: Do you have [plogr](https://cran.r-project.org/package=plogr) installed?

Comment: Yes - I have installed plogr, bindrcpp, dplyr, Rcpp.

Comment: Try adding `// [[Rcpp::depends(plogr)]]`

Comment: I had to reinstall the newer version of plogr, bind_rcpp and dply from github. The codes complies fine now but does complain that dplyr::DataFrameVisitors has no member named "subset". It seems like subset has been deprecated but I am not aware of the newer method as yet.

Answer (score 1):

As Ralf said, you may need to add other dependencies.

In this case, you need all these: `// [[Rcpp::depends(dplyr, plogr, bindrcpp)]]`.

Comment: Yes - thanks guys. I am not getting any compilation error anymore.

Comment: Looking at https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/master/inst/include/dplyr/DataFrameVisitors.h  - you will notice that subset is not a member function anymore for Class DataFrameVisitor

Comment: From what I understand of Stack Overflow, you must have one question for one error. You can't ask to solve all your possible issues at once. Otherwise, it would a code review site and won't be searchable for specific issues.

Comment: @MSWData This probably means that the original solution no longer works as well. Since you do not have enough rep, I have added a comment there.

Comment: @RalfStubner Thanks for your help and patience guys - really appreciate.