# how to sort an array in descending order using a boolean function?

Tags: c++, c++11

Since I am new in competitive programming so I am finding this a bit difficult. I encountered a code and I am not able to figure it out, need some help to understand it.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;
bool mycompare(int a ,int b){

    return a>b;
}

int main(){

    int a[]={5,4,3,1,2,6,7};
    int n =sizeof(a)/sizeof(int);

    sort(a,a+n,mycompare);

    for(int i=0; i<n;i++){
    cout<<a[i]<<"";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

```
output:
7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

How does this code work more specifically what does the mycompare function do in the code?

My doubt is that why haven't we passed any arguments in the `mycompare()` function inside the `main()` function since the prototype of the function is

```cpp
bool mycompare(int a, int b);
```

Comment: What *do* you understand about it, and what have you done to try and understand the rest?

Comment: If you want to learn how [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) work, you need to learn more about sorting and sorting algorithms in general. Then it should become very clear why a *comparison* function is needed and how it's used.

Comment: `mycompare` compares two integers using `greater than`. If `a` is greater than `b`, the function returns `true`. `std::sort` takes in a comparator to be used, which is the `mycompare` function in this case. So it sorts using that comparison.

Comment: mycompare function will be called internally by sort function.
you are just passing the address of function which need to used.
else default function will be called.

Answer (score 0):

A comparison-based sorting algorithm sorts the elements solely by pair-wise comparison, i.e., if `a < b` holds, then `a` has to be placed before `b`.

This is a fine approach, but if you limit yourself to using `<`, it only allows you to sort elements in an ascending order. What if you want to have them in descending order, or any other ordering? This is where the concept of a *Comparator* (or a [Compare](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) callable in the context of the C++ standard) comes into play: It is a binary predicate `bool compare(element a, element b)` that is supposed to replace the `<` operator, i.e., `a < b` becomes `compare(a, b)` instead. This generalization allows you to encapsulate all types of orderings, in your question you already provided an example where the comparison uses a greater-than operator `>`, which gives you the aforementioned descending sorted order.

As for how this works internally in C++, the details can be rather complicated, but you can look at it as this:

`mycompare` without any parameters is a function pointer, i.e. a pointer to the memory address where the machine code for `mycompare` starts. You can do something like

```
auto func_pointer = mycompare;
func_pointer(1, 2); // calls mycompare(1, 2)
```

By giving this function pointer as a parameter to `std::sort`, you replace the default `<` comparison function by your own. The way C++ works internally gives the additional advantage that this function call can most likely be *inlined*, i.e., the compiler avoids the function call can be avoided by copying the code from `mycompare` into the `std::sort` invocation, which can speed up your code significantly.

Answer (score -2):

[std::sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) takes a `RandomIt` (random iterator) as the first and second arguments that must satisfy the requirements of [ValueSwappable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ValueSwappable) and [LegacyRandomAccessIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator). Instead of using a *Plain-Old-Array* of `int`, you want to use [std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) which can then provide the iterators with the member functions `.begin()` and `.end()`.

Using a proper *container* from the C++ standard template library makes sorting with `std::sort` trivial. You need not even provide a custom compare function to sort in descending order as `std::less<int>()` is provided for you (though your purpose may be to provide the compare function)

Your prototype for `mycompare` will work fine as is, but preferably the parameters are `const type` rather than just `type`, e.g.

```
bool mycompare(const int a, const int b)
{
    return a > b;
}
```

The implementation using the array container is quite trivial. Simply declare/initialize your array `a` and then call `std::sort (a.begin(), a.end(), mycompare);` A complete working example would be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>

bool mycompare(const int a, const int b)
{
    return a > b;
}

int main (void) {

    std::array<int, 7> a = { 5, 4, 3, 1, 2, 6, 7 };

    std::sort (a.begin(), a.end(), mycompare);

    for (auto& i : a)
        std::cout << " " << i;
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/array_sort
 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

**Sorting the Plain Old Array***

If you must use a *Plain-Old-Array*, then you can use plain-old-pointers as your random iterrators. While not a modern C++ approach, you can handle the plain-old-array with `std::sort`. You can make use of the builtin `std::greater<type>()` for a descending sort or `std::less<type>()` for an ascending sort.

An implementation using pointers would simply be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main (void) {

    int a[] = { 5, 4, 3, 1, 2, 6, 7 };
    size_t n = sizeof a / sizeof *a;

#if defined (ASCEND)
    std::sort (a, a + n, std::less<int>());
#else
    std::sort (a, a + n, std::greater<int>());
#endif

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        std::cout << " " << a[i];
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

(same output unless `-DASCEND` is added as a define on the commandline, and then an ascending sort will result from the use of `std::less<int>()`)

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: I would like to point out that all pointers to Swappable types fulfill the type requirements of `std::sort`, as pointers are the model example of a `RandomAccessIterator`. So while it is maybe not "modern C++" style to use them, there is nothing inherently wrong with it either. Especially the reference to `qsort` seems harmful to me.

Comment: I would not recommend any algorithms from the C standard library as long as there are alternatives in the C++ standard library. Also, due to the additional indirection introduced by the comparator function pointer, `qsort` is most likely much slower than the corresponding `std::sort`, which is especially important in competitive programming. Your second sentence seems to imply that you need additional boilerplate code to use `std::sort` with raw pointers. That is not the case, as I tried to clarify in my first comment.

Comment: I've updated with a Pointer example for code pre-STL.

Comment: I would be really surprised if gcc was using the exact same sorting code as the basis for `qsort` and `std::sort` when it comes down to it. The gcc `qsort` is a highly optimizes blend of *quicksort* utilizing an *insertion sort* when the number of partitions falls below 16 at my last check. It's always somewhat a "rabbit-trail" to snake through the git tree hopping from file to file to chase down the included pieces and macros. But I do agree with you, if C++ provides it, it's better to use it compared to where there is no C++ implementation, like `strtok`, etc..

Comment: My claim was actually a bit stronger: Even if they both implemented the fastest state-of-the-art sorting algorithms, `qsort` could never come close to `std::sort`, since it cannot inline the comparator function pointer. There are [many](https://travisdowns.github.io/blog/2019/05/22/sorting.html) [benchmarks](https://martin-ueding.de/articles/qsort-vs-std-sort/index.html) [to that effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708105/performance-of-qsort-vs-stdsort).

Comment: Those are good links. The [qsort vs. std::sort](https://martin-ueding.de/articles/qsort-vs-std-sort/index.html) doesn't show a great disparity among `qsort` and `std::sort` for the gcc/g++ implementation or even between that and the clang/clang++ results as well. I guess the numbers could diverge more as the number of elements exceeds the 10E7 range shown on the graph, but what's there is in line with what I would expect.

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to continue this discussion further. Just note that the blog post you mentioned uses logarithmic scales for runtimes and speedups, and mentions a speedup of roughly 2 between `std::sort` and `qsort` for large inputs. This is also reflected in the other benchmarks I listed.